# How to open Cash Drawer that is connected with a thermal printer?

Tags: java

Im using Epson JPOS ADK for my thermal printer, I connect the CashDrawer using RJ-12 cable but it wont open the CashDrawer. I can print with my thermal printer.

here is my code:

```
    System.setProperty(JposPropertiesConst.JPOS_POPULATOR_FILE_PROP_NAME, "jpos_path");
    POSPrinterControl114 printer = (POSPrinterControl114) new POSPrinter();
    CashDrawerControl114 cashDrawer = (CashDrawerControl114) new CashDrawer();

    try {
        printer.open("POSPrinter");
        printer.claim(1000);
        printer.setDeviceEnabled(true);
        printer.printNormal(POSPrinterConst.PTR_S_RECEIPT, "Test Print\n");


        cashDrawer.open("CashDrawer");
        cashDrawer.claim(1000);
        cashDrawer.setDeviceEnabled(true);

        cashDrawer.openDrawer();

    } catch (JposException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        try {
            cashDrawer.setDeviceEnabled(false);
            cashDrawer.release();
            cashDrawer.close();

            printer.setDeviceEnabled(false);
            printer.release();
            printer.close();

        } catch (JposException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: how did you find answer to your question ?

Comment: have you found the solution?

Answer (score 0):

make sure that your printerConnection is connected and try this way

```
printerConnection.write(byteArrayOf(0x1B, 0x70, 0x00, 0x3C, 0xFF.toByte()))
printerConnection.send(100)
```

also you have method openCashBox() inside your EscPosPrinter library